# Can a lazy iterator for the keys of an object be implemented in ES5 JavaScript without loading all keys of the object into memory at once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iterator, generator

I want to write a ES5 JavaScript function (i.e. without generators or `Symbol.iterator`) that accomplishes what the following generator function does in ES6:

```js
function *keys(o) {
  for (let key in o)
    yield key
}
```

I want to return a lazy iterator **without loading all of the keys into memory at once**, so `Object.keys` is off the table since it returns an array of the keys. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I was getting desperate so I started looking into how generators are transpiled into versions of JavaScript which do not support them. If you input the generator function above into [Facebook's Regenerator](https://facebook.github.io/regenerator), you get the following output:

```js
var _marked =
/*#__PURE__*/
regeneratorRuntime.mark(keys);

function keys(o) {
  var key;
  return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function keys$(_context) {
    while (1) {
      switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
        case 0:
          _context.t0 = regeneratorRuntime.keys(o);

        case 1:
          if ((_context.t1 = _context.t0()).done) {
            _context.next = 7;
            break;
          }

          key = _context.t1.value;
          _context.next = 5;
          return key;

        case 5:
          _context.next = 1;
          break;

        case 7:
        case "end":
          return _context.stop();
      }
    }
  }, _marked, this);
}
```

After reading through this output I thought that the implementation of `regeneratorRuntime.keys` might hold the answer, but it appears that this function loads all of the keys into memory at once:

```js
exports.keys = function(object) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var key in object) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
  keys.reverse();

  // Rather than returning an object with a next method, we keep
  // things simple and return the next function itself.
  return function next() {
    while (keys.length) {
      var key = keys.pop();
      if (key in object) {
        next.value = key;
        next.done = false;
        return next;
      }
    }

    // To avoid creating an additional object, we just hang the .value
    // and .done properties off the next function object itself. This
    // also ensures that the minifier will not anonymize the function.
    next.done = true;
    return next;
  };
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt there's any way to do it. There's no standard interface that allows you to get pointers to object properties or access them through a numeric index. Is this just an academic exercise or do you have a real need for this?

Comment: It is more of an academic exercise, but I think it would be useful for writing code which transforms objects in a functional style without allocating memory unnecessarily.

Comment: All of the keys on an object are *already* in memory by my understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong). The only cost of `Object.keys` is making an `Array` with a shallow copy of the keys (which would normally just mean an `Array` with enough spaces for `#keys` pointers, which isn't a whole lot). Your JS engine might even JIT this to remove the actual `Array` if it's never stored/mutated, accessing the keys directly on demand (not to be counted on, but then, the cost of an array of pointers is pretty trivial). This seems a premature optimization at best, based on a misunderstanding of JS.

Comment: I do believe that the keys of an object are already in memory. I suppose I should have asked if there was a way to do it without allocating an array to store the keys when I should be able to just iterate over them where ever it is they are already stored. I agree that the performance difference would probably be negligible; I was just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to create a lazy property iterator. ES6 had [`Reflect.enumerate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/enumerate), and generator functions allow you to write that `keys` helper, but in ES5 no such facility exists - given that ES5 did not have any iterator concept, that's not surprising.